# Is there a way for an author to accept/improve a suggested edit after it's been rejected?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4613231) is a suggested edit that was rejected.  Rejection is questionable, since it really was offering an improvement, not commenting.  But I can see where the reviewers were coming from.

However, if that information had been properly left in comments, I as the post author would choose to include it.

Is there a way for me, as the author, to accept a variation of the edit, as if I were one of the first three reviewers and had hit the "Improve" button?  Would it make sense to offer the author the "Accept" and "Improve" buttons even after rejection?

Comment: Note that using the markdown view of the rejected edit makes it fairly easy to copy+paste the suggestions, and I've done so.  But it would be less work to start with the edited version.  Having a merge tool for the differences would be even better.

Comment: For the record, I started writing my answer before seeing your comment. ;)

Comment: This has been discussed on Meta Stack Exchange: [Allow the owner of a post to approve a suggested edit even if it was rejected by reviewers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by)

Comment: @hichris123 of course, but we should not flag those just yet, I did it once and flag was rejected: "Don't worry about dupes for now". Guess they prefer to have those things both on MSO and MSE for the time being.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, I know. Just wanted to point the asker to that question, as it helps to explain everything.

Comment: @hichris123: Yup, that's exactly the same issue.  It isn't completely clear whether this belongs on meta.so or not.  What I'm sure of is that platform changes inspired by other sites no longer belong here.

Comment: @ben this feature request on MSE might be useful to you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252913/245360

Comment: @PatrickHofman: If by "useful", you meant "candidate for closing as a duplicate"

Comment: @PatrickHofman: It's a dupe of the one hichris linked above.

Comment: Ah. Indeed. That would be a valid close target. Nice catch!

Comment: Just to bump this question: I just had a similar situation [with this edit to one of my answers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10765090) - the edit was rejected, but the editor was absolutely correct. I'd like to be able to approve the edit so as to credit the editor. I can't see where this has been addressed yet as I suppose it's an infrequent issue, but IMO it would be reasonable to allow posters to approve edits to their posts, irregardless of review queue results.

Comment: Had the same problem and came to the same conclusion as Bob :)

Answer (score 7):

No, that's not possible. Once a suggested edit is reviewed (either approved or rejected) it's done and can't be reviewed again, and we can't have access to it's "source" as it's not a revision.

What you can do is click the "markdown" diff option then copy the relevant changes into your own post:

> [image]

Comment: Yep, did that.  (My comment and your post crossed)  Still would be more streamlined to choose to improve the edit.

Comment: And it would also give credit and reputation to the original editor, and would not count towards an edit ban

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi That's questionable, as noted in [my duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269439/allow-owner-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-after-its-rejected) -- that opens up a significant loophole. Anyway, the main proposal here is to make it easier for an owner to take a proposed but rejected edit.

Comment: @tripleee You could still automatically apply a suggested edit and reject it, by clicking the Improve button and unchecking "suggested edit was helpful".

Comment: This is for when it is no longer in review, when a sufficient number of reviewers have voted to reject it; then there is bo "Improve" button. Obviously when it's still in review, it can trivially be accepted by the owner of the question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing it would be to not touch the rejected review but in case of a rejected review give the suggested edit another round in a special loop where post owners and only post owners can approve or reject the suggested edits again. Remove them from the second loop if the post owner does not decide within two weeks or if another edit happens during the same time. However if the edit is approved, give the +2 rep.

This proposed two stage reviewing of the suggested edits is easy to implement because it is a simple addition not interfering with anything else.

Comment: I just saw that the [discussion on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by) basically asks for the same solution.