# Allow owner to approve a suggested edit even after it's rejected

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

A newbie suggested an edit to an answer of mine.  I got a notification, but by the time I was looking at it, others had already reviewed and rejected it.

Now, I basically agree with the review; as per site policy, code changes should not be approved. Still, the edit was actually useful, and it would have been **easier** for me to just overrule the review.  Now, I had to reimplement the (admittedly minor) change myself.

In addition, in an ideal world, I could have awarded the helpful newbie some karma (if not actual rep score) by doing so.

I can imagine other scenarios where a radical change is (rightfully) rejected by reviewers on the grounds of being too invasive, but the owner could still agree to take the change if it's actually warranted.  These things probably don't happen very frequently, but when it does, it sucks to have to repeat the change.

Could we please add this feature?

Comment: The [details](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5592109) are so boring I did not want to include them in the question.  The OP changed the code in his question (boo hiss) and the edit suggested the corresponding change in my answer.

Comment: How can an edit be useful and not useful? Can you link to the suggestion?

Comment: @ChrisF: It's linked in the comment above. It violated accepted policy (do not edit code) so it was rejected for that, but under the circumstances, the change was warranted, and I would have approved it.

Comment: Perhaps on answer-edit-suggestions, we should also indicate whether the question was changed shortly before, especially by the proposer?

Comment: Only now do I realize that the suggested edit came from the OP.  (I thought that nick looked familiar!)  Oh well.  Question still stands.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by

Answer (score 2):

If the edit is incorrect as per site policy, then it's important for the edit to be rejected so that the user learns that these types of edits aren't appropriate, and that they need to comment instead.

Approving the edit is encouraging them to continue to perform inappropriate behavior, which we don't want to be encouraging.

Comment: Noted, but being able to salvage / harvest the work already spent on the edit would still be useful, especially if it's substantial (but don't underestimate the usability impact of minor chores, either).

Comment: @tripleee You already can see the changes and apply them to your own post manually without a significant amount of effort, especially given that you can view the markup of a suggested edit and just copy-paste.

Comment: Sometimes it is helpful to mention why the edit was necessary in the edit description. When indicating there why this edit is necessary (even if it had to be rejected by just looking at the content, without context), I surprisingly got those trough review.

Comment: @martin Getting invalid edits through review isn't exactly an accomplishment.  Review is a completely broken system.  The review system approves things like spam and obvious vandalism.  Getting an edit actually rejected by review is what's an accomplishment.

Comment: If I make a typo in an answer which significantly changes the meaning, it would be easier for me to see a suggested change with an "approve?" button than to read a comment "Should the fifth word of the second sentence of paragraph three be 'note' rather than 'not'", then identify the error, and correct it myself.  On the other hand, I've sometimes had posts of mine incorrectly edited (and the edits approved) because someone thought I'd made a mistake when what I wrote had been correct.

Comment: @supercat And a typo being corrected where the authors intent is maintained is an example of an appropriate edit, not an inappropriate edit.