# Allow undoing of edit rejection

Tags: feature-request

When I opened SO today I got a notification for an edit being made in one of my answers.

The editor found two gross mistakes in my answer and suggested a couple of changes which would make it correct. However, it was rejected, with the reason being:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

My mistakes were so basic that even someone who is just beginning in the technology involved would have easily spotted it at a glance. Thus, I believe the rejectors didn't even bother to see what was being changed, basing their decision on the relatively small reputation of the editor.

[This was the edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5720736)

Since rejections can't be undone, I went there and fixed the mistakes myself, leaving a note of thanks to the editor. I would like to propose this as a feature, though.

I have seen this similar question: [Allow owner to approve a suggested edit even after it's rejected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269439/allow-owner-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-after-its-rejected). I would propose that users with a golden badge on a technology should be able to undo rejections as well.

Comment: The answer is effectively the same as your linked question.  Just adding the additional gold badge feature doesn't make it different.  The community has decided that **suggested** edits that change the code, even to fix obvious mistakes, are not generally acceptable and should be avoided.

Comment: Is there somewhere where I can read about that decision?

Comment: @psubsee2003 The reviewing guidelines say no such thing.  It's inappropriate to edit a post to change the content from what the author intended (this applies equally to code and non-code).  If it's clear what the author intended to do and they made a mistake in doing it, whether in code or not, it's appropriate to fix it.  *That* is the editing guidelines.  The consensus that *was* made is that if an edit is rejected the post author shouldn't have the ability to retroactively change it.  They can re-apply or roll back the edit if they want, but they can't change the review action taken.

Comment: I can only disagree with all these requests about "undoing rejections." Allowing users to go back and change previous actions is just not something that should matter. Review was completed, it got rejected, it's done. End of story. If *you* think the edits were valid, apply them yourself. I don't think attribution to the person who pointed out the mistake is important enough to warrant additional complications in the system. We don't attribute edits to people who *comment* to point out mistakes, even though under the same logic the edit is "theirs."