# How to reverse a edit rejection on my own answer, to give credit to the original editor?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Today I received a notice on this proposed edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5733580 which was for very poor reasons, rejected - the edit is valid and correct.

Now, there is no way for me to approve the edit (even though its my answer). I could always edit my answer and implement the change, but then the editor (a new user) would not get the much deserved points.

Is there a solution to this problem? If not, something should be implemented.  Right off the bat I can see potential for abuse, if someone wants to team up and then approve rejected edits just to get their friend some points; so I suppose a limit should be put in place for these.  I was originally going to suggest to have an option to notify a moderator about it and let them reverse the changes, but I believe moderators already have their queues full on a busy site like stackoverflow.

I guess in addition to a discussion on my proposal, what I would really like to know is what can I do in this situation as I feel poorly for the guy who suggested a perfectly valid edit, and yet got unceremoniously rejected.

Comment: Two points doesn't seem like that big a deal c.c

Comment: Its a very big deal if you are sitting on 1 point; more importantly, it lets a new user know that they are doing something right.

Comment: I totally agree with @BurhanKhalid: I don't care about the +2, but I do like the green indicator because it tells me that the _time_ and _effort_ I spent was a useful contribution.

Comment: Regardless to the feature-request, the problem is there was no indicator that the reviewers *had the skill related to the technology/tag* to know that the edit was valid, and moreover, editing code in answer is always a debated issue. Just move on, people make mistakes, and let the editor get his reps from other more substantial/clear edits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow owner to approve a suggested edit even after it's rejected](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269439). See also: [Is there a way for an author to accept/improve a suggested edit after it's been rejected?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251337), [Allow undoing of edit rejection](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270922), and [Allow the owner of a post to approve a suggested edit even if it was rejected by reviewers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by)