# Let author approve rejected “Suggested Edits”

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I don't understand how Suggested Edits work.

I got a notification (seemingly yesterday) that an edit was suggested to my question:

[image]

Today I opened it, and somehow it was already rejected:

[image]

The edit is **totally reasonable** and I'm going to include it myself.
I have no idea it was rejected by three people.
I want this edit to be included.

But the interface won't let me do that.
I scrolled up and down several times and there is no "Approve" button.

Comment: Sorry, just realized it's a dupe of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251337/is-there-a-way-for-an-author-to-accept-improve-a-suggested-edit-after-its-been) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by).