# Let author write an opinion when rolling back an accepted suggested edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There was an edit on my answer by a relatively unexperienced user, he broke the new-lines in my text, but only one reviewer noticed that. In my opinion, the user also didn't add anything helpful. However, the edit was still accepted.

[image]

I was notified to review the suggested changes, but there was no way for me to step in, give my opinion or improve the edit to fix the errors.

I decided to roll back the changes, but I could not describe my decision, I also attempted to edit the rollback to add a summary, but it didn't get saved. As I didn't want to look egoistic and start a roll-back war, I had to create a new edit on my post to add an Edit Summary.

There are several topics mentioned to discuss that may be related to other questions, but they are not solved yet in their respective SO questions.

- Reviewers failed to notice an error
- Let author vote in the review
- Let user write a summary on a roll-back

[Leave comment when rolling back an edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271924/leave-comment-when-rolling-back-an-edit)
[Let author approve rejected “Suggested Edits”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271530/let-author-approve-rejected-suggested-edits)
[Is there a way for an author to accept/improve a suggested edit after it's been rejected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251337/is-there-a-way-for-an-author-to-accept-improve-a-suggested-edit-after-its-been)
[What to do when OP rolls back a clarifying edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309509/what-to-do-when-op-rolls-back-a-clarifying-edit)

Comment: *I also attempted to edit the rollback to add a summary, but it didn't get saved* - really? That smells like a bug then, according to Shog in the first link that should work.

Comment: I thought that was because I didn't add any text to the edit. From my experience: When you make an edit and then want to update the Summary, you need to introduce new changes to the text, save, edit again, remove the changes and add desired summary. All within the 5 minutes if you don't want to create new edits.

Comment: @Qwerty: When you click "edit" on a previous revision, enter a summary and save without making any changes to the text it is submitted as a rollback with the added summary. Or at least, it should.

Comment: @BoltClock It did not save my Summary message after clicking edit on the rollback in the revisions view. I did try that within the 5 minute span.

Comment: @Qwerty: Strange. The 5-minute grace period is irrelevant for the purposes of rollbacks. You should have been able to roll it back.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh, sorry for confusing you. I was able to roll back to a previous version, but I could not change the rollback summary message where I intended to justify my doing.

Comment: @Tunaki I did find and read this QA, but since I have already made the rollback, the method seemed confusing to me. I now understand better how it has to be done. Even though there are still issues I would like to see discussed, I will mark this as duplicate as they somewhat surpass the extent of this QA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see now. You were trying to annotate a rollback *after* you had submitted the rollback. That's not possible. A rollback cannot be modified once it has been submitted (except by moderators, and only in extreme circumstances). Attempting to edit to add a summary with no changes after the fact then gets treated as any other blank edit, and is discarded.

In future, if you want to annotate a rollback, you need to make sure you click "edit" instead of "rollback" on the revision you intend to roll back to. You can add a summary there and submit, which will result in a rollback with your summary.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand my problem with being unable to alter the rollback summary message. But why is it that obscure? Since the other two topics somewhat surpass the extent of this question, I will mark it as duplicate. Though I would still like see the topics being discussed somewhere.