# Giving proper credit to low-rep user

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, privileges

Today I received a notification about a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6723013) on one of my answers. It seems that the package in question was updated, so the edit proposed a minor fix to the code. 
Reviewers rejected the edit, giving an advice to comment instead. Ironically, this is a useless recommendation, since the user has only 13 rep and doesn't have the privilege to do so.

As it turns out, the edit was indeed helpful, and I updated my post. It was also nice that the user left an expanded explanation. Naturally, I wanted to thank him for the effort. Keep in mind that this is his first suggested edit, so rejecting it without giving a credit for the attention to the problem would be very unfortunate.

My first thought was to drop him a note in chat, but he does not have this privilege either. So I left a comment for him, but I'm not sure he'll receive a notification. The main question is, what else can be done in such (a very rare) situation? It's not only about the +2, it's more about changing the impression that we as a community may have created by rejecting the first helpful edit.

I thought of dropping an "occasional" upvote on his only question, but I do not know if a) that's a good one; b) this is a proper course of action. I decided I'd ask on meta first.

Comment: [code edit rejection](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code "see detailed discussion here") was likely the right decision for reviewers. Worth keeping in mind that you as a post author are in a different position than them and can afford to approve riskier suggestions. As for thanking the user who suggested an edit, if it feels really important, I'd probably just add a comment under my own post about this (assuming that they will re-check the post that they attempted to edit)

Comment: @gnat I totally agree that rejecting was justified.

Comment: You can use your votes however you like, so if the user has a [well presented question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220184/chrome-issues-with-display-inline-for-select-option-tags), and you want to share the love,  feel free to give them an upvote.

Comment: If a user suggests an edit on a question, you can reply to the comment with @username (though it won't appear as a dropdown option).  So you are able to notify them.

Comment: Good edits being rejected in-order to err on the side of caution (I do such rejections a lot  myself) is one thing that makes me wonder if allowing the owner of the post to *override* the reviewers decision *even after the review has been completed* would be a good addition. Some reviewers might initially take offence to being overridden but I guess over time they will realize that an override doesn't mean that they were wrong.

Comment: I think he has received some extra credit over the last 2 days :)

Comment: @Matt, if by extra credit you mean 15 (and counting) upvotes, then yes. (Previously had a score of 2 after 2.5 years)  The meta effect really skews things on low-traffic questions/tags (not good).

Comment: Yeh it was kind of a back handed comment ;)

Comment: @Harry This is a good idea. The post owner could be notified of any suggested edit and kind of adopt the suggested edit, independent of any reviewer decision. This should be a feature proposal. Also reviewers should skip not reject if they cannot judge the subject.

Comment: @tonytonov Nice to see someone being so considerate. I can't speak with authority, but since there's no perfect solution I don't think there's anything wrong with giving his question an upvote unless it's a poor question.

Comment: @Trilarion: Yes mate. Looks like there is already a [proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251337/is-there-a-way-for-an-author-to-accept-improve-a-suggested-edit-after-its-been).

Comment: I would love the ability to override reviewers verdicts on my own post. I have had reviewers reject edits to my answers that were helpful, and I have also had reviewers accept edits to my answers that made them incorrect.

Comment: The Problem for Low Rep users is: You have an Idea and want to comment it -> Doesent work -> Write as Answer (even with the comment to it that ist a comment and not an answer) -> get Downvoted becouse ist not an Answer -> Less Rep! That was really anoying for me

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Please only vote up a question or answer that you think is **useful / good in its own right**, not because you're trying to reward the user for other contributions. Similarly for downvoting and non-useful / bad posts.

**We want the best posts to have the highest scores**, not the posts by the best users (even though the overlap between those are significant). Good users can also have less good / useful posts.

Beyond that, for better or worse, **Stack Overflow is more post-centric than maintenance-centric** - the majority of a user's reputation generally comes from posts, not maintenance. Maintenance should be more for those who care about the site rather than just caring about reputation, so the little reputation boost (which no longer gets applied at higher reputation, by the way) should be a nice addition, but not necessary to keep up the contribution.

Also, if the user has made multiple posts and you use their profile to find them and vote on them (even only the useful ones), you will more than likely trigger the [serial-voting](/questions/tagged/serial-voting) script (reverting the votes and having more dire consequences for constant offenders), because it gives the posts of users targeted like this an unfair advantage.

---

This advice is perhaps a little arguable, but...

If you want you can **post a comment on their question** thanking them for their edit (noting that you've applied it) and ask them to keep trying to make the site a better place, perhaps noting that such edits might get rejected as reviewers might not be familiar with the language and leaving a comment pointing out the problem would be better (and pointing out that they may want to try and post a few useful questions or answers to try to get that 50 reputation that they require to comment). You may also point out an unfortunately broken system if you still have characters to spare.

Try to, after a few days, if the user has been online in that time, **delete the comment** as not to leave irrelevant content for others to clean up. You should similarly delete the comment directly after the user has replied, followed by flagging their reply as obsolete or similar.

Comment: Post a comment *on their question*? I think you mean, a comment on your own answer with a @ shoutout (which [has now happened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018598/add-a-plot-title-to-ggvis/25030002#comment44234736_25030002)).

Comment: @tripleee @ shoutouts only ping their recipients if the recipient is already participating in the post somehow (it's their Q or A or they made a comment or edit there).

Comment: Which they did?  Or does having your edit rejected count as not making an edit?  (That's a bug in my book.)

Comment: @tripleee Yes, [you can *not* notify a user (with an @ comment) who's only post participation is a rejected edit suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), so yes, a comment on their question.

Answer (score 13):

Is this right?

> Tanner's comment as an answer:
>
> > You can use your votes however you like, so if the user has a well presented question, and you want to share the love, feel free to give them an upvote.

I think the above direction is semantically wrong. Do not reward people by upvoting unrelated material.

However, I think it is fine to reward them by paying attention to their as-yet under-noticed material. If, while paying attention to their material, you find it is under-appreciated, especially in relation to other material on the site, do the right thing by appreciating it in its correct context.

If there is no under-appreciated material by them, or even if there is, also simply thanking them in a comment with something like the following would be completely appropriate:

> @foobar, thanks for your edit, it *was* useful, and I have applied it.

The system is good, but not perfect. A comment like the above will help rectify it when it misfires.

Answer (score 5):

I would make a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that, either.

I think the reputation settings are a bit overbearing. I can't tell you how many times I've had a good reason to do something only to be told "Hey! You can't do that because you're at 13 reputation."

It's also an issue that those who have whatever large amount of reputation are no more correct or helpful than those with little reputation. I can't tell you how many times I ask a question and an answerer links me to a completely irrelevant question telling me the answer I'm looking for is there, then decides to mark my question as a duplicate when I was asking something completely separate from the other question. That's the main thing that kept happening and I'd lose the privelege to even ask a question, so I probably have around three or four accounts here now. This one hasn't been shut down yet.

I mean, even the most technical and specific questions will be marked as duplicates and the supposedly duplicated question has nothing to do with my question! Sorry. I needed to vent. Hopefully staff will read this and become a bit more lenient with the reputation settings.

It doesn't bother me much, though. Eventually I'll be using 10minutemail in order to ask a question.

Comment: Questions need to explain what you're not trying to do also.  If someone proposes a duplicate of doing X, when your question clearly says that you are not doing X, we (the high rep users) will jump all over them and make sure the question doesn't get closed.  Of course, this only applies to similar tasks... if the task is *really* different, then the person proposing the dupe is just an idiot... but if four others agree, that means it is close and you didn't clearly explain the difference.

Comment: Gotcha. Hopefully that will stop happening. It hasn't happened in a while, but that's because I try not to ask many questions out of fear they'll be downvoted so hard I lose another account.

Comment: A good guideline is that if the title of some other question was close enough that you had to click on it hoping it had your answer, it's close enough to be a danger of bad dupe, so point out the difference / where the other answers fell short.

Comment: Trying to use the system with low rep is frustrating, but it's not hard to reach a reasonable reputation level.  I was skeptical but then relatively rapidly found myself reaching 1.5k, then 2k, then 3k, then 10k just through using the site actively. From my experience, answering questions is probably the way to go, rather than by asking questions. There's a thin line between helping newbies by answering simple questions competently and accurately on one hand, and what is condescendingly known as rep whoring, though. I wish there was a reward for marking questions as duplicates...

Comment: The site is run by the community to a large extent. If you want to suggest a change in how the reputation limits are applied, post a suggestion here on meta.

Comment: What is 'rep whoring'?

Comment: [Definition of rep whore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19522#19522) (from *The Many Memes of Meta*).

Comment: If you are an expert on some programming language, try to answer questions on it. I am a programming learner, not a real expert, so I made a workaround: I picked another SE site on topic I knew well enough to make good answers, and quickly I made 200 points, so I got 100 point association bonus here on SO, bypassing most low-rep issues. Click at "StackExchange" in upper left corner and find a community that might suit you, there are lots of them.

Comment: @BenVoigt 'Super Users' are able to close a question immediately as a duplicate, so no voting process here.

Comment: @cybermonkey: But only in tags where they hold a gold badge... so while it's not impossible they make a mistake in selecting a dupe, it is a strong sign that the two are easily confused and the new question needs to clarify the difference.

Comment: I can't believe someone would actually take their time to rep whore. I don't think answers should be posted unless they're useful or potentially helpful! I've somehow earned around 60 reputation in the past 24 hours, so that's definitely giving me more hope for this site and potentially not becoming another fail. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

I just cite [Tanner's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283357/giving-proper-credit-to-low-rep-user#comment141435_283357) as an answer:

> You can use your votes however you like, so if the user has a well
>   presented question, and you want to share the love, feel free to give
>   them an upvote.

As an addition: Giving proper credit by citing the source (his name) is probably also a good idea.

Comment: in my opionion unfortunately the willness to downvote is higher than to upvote

Comment: @Mephiztopheles But if you really want to give proper credit why not upvote?

Comment: I'm sorry.. was angry about some bad reply on a simple question...
If i understood you right...

Comment: @Trilarion: Because we should vote on the content, not on the user? Doing it otherwise is really bad, whichever direction it goes.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, I understand that. Problem is here that there is no direct way of voting on the content. But if by chance another contribution of the author is worth upvoting than why not doing it. What do you prefer: going by the rules exactly or going by the spirit of the rules? Also consider that you are quite free to give out your votes here as you like. Probably a lot of people do not a 100% vote for content but are also biased by the name that stands below the contribution or other factors.

Comment: Sure, go ahead and lavish some extra-attention on his contributions (which mostly means enhancing them with edits and constructive comments though). Just don't vote as you wouldn't organically, nor vote too focused or much.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the privilege to post a comment, so I will just write an answer.
as I am low repped at the moment I know exactly what you mean. Sometimes I read a question, But not quite sure about the question. I can't simply ask it to clearify his answer since I can't post any comments.

Sometimes I am quite sure I know the answer on a question, but I don't answer the question pure because I don't want to post a answer wich I am not sure to be right, because you get -1 spams if you answer with the wrong answer.

If I just could post comments, it would me much better !